# Epsilon-Delta proof of limit as $(x,y)\to 0,0)$ of $\sin(x^2+y^2)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am trying to come up with an epsilon delta proof of 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}sin(x^2+y^2)=0.$$

I know I have to find the form square root of $x^2+y^2 < \delta$, but the only thing I know is that the absolute value of $\sin (x^2+y^2) <= 1$

Thanks!

Comment: $x\to 0,\ y\to 0$ imply $x^2+y^2\to 0$, while $sin(u)$ is continuous and $sin(0)=0$ should be enough.

Comment: $\sin(x^2 + y^2) \le x^2 + y^2 = \delta^2.$  Let $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of the fact that for $0 < z < 1$, $0 < \sin z < z$.

For $0 < x, y < 1$, then, $0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1$, and hence $0 < \sin (x^2 + y^2) < x^2 + y^2$.

From this point, we can then use the squeeze theorem and state that since $x^2 + y^2 \rightarrow 0$ in the given limit, $\sin (x^2 + y^2)$ must also approach $0$. You can dress that up in $\epsilon-\delta$ notation as required.